# Git undo - make sure that local files are the same as a previous commit on Git

Tags: git

Please help I'm new to Git - Something has gone seriously wrong in my application and I want to restore a previous commit - but nothing is working - No matter what I do I still see the later files on my local hard drive.  How can I restore to a previous commit and make sure that this is what I have to work with on my local machine?

Comment: What does `git status` output?

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't pushed, try `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Otherwise `git revert HEAD` will create a commit exactly the opposite of what you did on your latest commit.

You can also specify a commit hash instead of HEAD to undo a specific commit.

Answer (score 1):

Resetting back to a last commit:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Be aware that all uncommitted changes will be discarded. This will revert all files back to the last committed state. HEAD can also be edited to match a sha1 hash of the commit to revert to a specific commit.

For more info on resetting, read this: http://progit.org/2011/07/11/reset.html

Comment: Thanks for your speedy reply and help -  I have done this but it still seems that my local files are not updating?  I also then deleted previous commits (not sure how I did this - I've been going round in circles for hours) but I have on git hub now got back to about 3 commits previous - which is where I'd like to be - but it's not reflected in my local files - I've been using commands like pull as well - but nothing seems to work

Comment: What does `git status` say? Any changes can be reverted with `git checkout -- .` to ensure the file listing mirrors the last commit.

Comment: Luwe - I finally got it to work - what a brilliant link  - finally I think I'm beginning to grasp what Git is trying to do - it's been just a mystery - and none of the documentation explains it as simply as the link you supplied - thankyou so much.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you can temporary unapply local changes with `git stash`. You can get these changes back with `git stash apply`.

When the problem is not in your local changes, you can check out older revisions with `git checkout <commit-id>`, where commit-id is either the hash of the commit, a branch name or a special reference like HEAD^. You are on a [detached head](http://marklodato.github.com/visual-git-guide/index-en.html#detached) afterwards, which means if you want to do any code changes on the checked out revision you must create a new branch from this revision (`git checkout -b <new-branchname>`).